# What is the simplification of $ {e^2}^n $?

Tags: euler-mascheroni-constant

I'm stuck on this problem, can someone tell me what the simplification of the following is?

$$\ {e^2}^n $$

Comment: $e^{2^n}$......

Comment: I was thinking that it could just be simplified down to $$\ 2^n $$ , but I'm not sure...

Comment: No, that is not true

Comment: yeah, k........

Comment: @ZacharySelk Could be $e^{2^n}=k^n$ for a $k$.?

Comment: @MyGlasses No, $e^{2^n}$ diverges much more quickly than $k^n$ for any $k>0$.

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{ni}}{i!}$

Answer (score 2):

The default is that ${e^2}^n$ is read as $e^{(2^n)}$, for which there is no simplification.  In fact, the reason given for the default is the lack of a simplification. It becomes larger than $k^n$ for any $k$ once $n$ is large enough.

Comment: nope, not missing anything, $$\ {e^2}^n $$ is exactly what i meant.

Comment: OK, I deleted the part about that.